# Check if first segment of URL is not file or directory

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I have a rewrite rule in my web.config file like this:

```
  <rule name="Public page" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
      <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.(.*)$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public/place/{R:2}.aspx?cname={R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

What it does is let the client type in a dynamic place name and then the page he wants to see. e.g., I have a page that displays news for companies. I want to see news for a company named "Pavilion" so I type:

```
http://localhost/pavilion/news/
```

and the URL rewrite takes me to

```
http://localhost/public/news.aspx?cname=pavilion
```

That works. But I'm getting a lot of errors about page not found for case like this: An image's src attribute that points to some Non Existing name from another page.
e.g., in products page (http://localhost/products/showproducts.aspx) I have:

```
<img src='undefined'/>
```

when I debug I see that it fires the rule thinking that **products** is {R:2} and **undefined** is {R:1}
so it tries to load `http://localhost/products/undefined/` and I get the error: `The file '/public/undefined.aspx' does not exist.`

I would like the rule not to fire if the first segment of the url is directory or file.
Does any one has an idea how can I do such a check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the back-reference in condition input string.

```
 <rule name="Public page" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.(.*)$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}\{R:1}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}\{R:1}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="public/place/{R:2}.aspx?cname={R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Thanks to [Leo](http://forums.iis.net/t/1187910.aspx) for the answer